# Version Number of App in executable name

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'd like to set the builds name in Visual Studio to something like that:
MyApp_{VERSION}_x32.exe

Under project settings I can define the Output file name "Release\MyApp.exe"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by [adding a new property sheet to your project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k4a0033%28VS.80%29.aspx). Name it as you like, then open it with the property manager view. Now:

1. add a new user defined property, name it `Version` and set it to your value of choice
2. set your output file (in *link editor*) to `$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName)_$(Version).exe`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a renamer app that can grab the VERSION from an exe and rename it accordingly.

In the project that you would like to compile to MyApp_{VERSION}_x32.exe for example. You could set the post build project option to run the renamer app on the exe currently being compiled.

So everytime you build your app the rename app gets ran, it then renames the newly built exe.

I hope this helps.